# Double confirmation pop up in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Tried to make double confirmation pop up. If I click on button the pop up opens. here if I click on yes button it should go for button page(first page). If I click on no another window should open with OK button. If I click on OK button all pop up should be closed.

```js
function confirmation(question) {
  var defer = $.Deferred();
  $('<div></div>')
    .html(question)
    .dialog({
      autoOpen: true,
      buttons: {
        "Yes": function() {
          defer.resolve("true");
        },
        "No": function() {
          defer.resolve("false");

        }
      },


    });
  return defer.promise();
};

function onclick() {
  var question = "Do you want to add record?";
  confirmation(question).then(function(answer) {
    console.log(answer);
    var ansbool = (String(answer) == "true");
    if (ansbool) {
      //  alert("this is obviously " + ansbool);//TRUE
    } else {
      // alert("and then there is " + ansbool);//FALSE
    }
  });
}

$("#item").on('click', onclick);
```

```css
#item:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="item">click me.</button>
```

Comment: You don't have a `div` in HTML and `.dialog` is a property of JQuery UI.

Comment: I did it. My code is working thanks.